# Dogecoin daemon (dogecoind) not responding to RPC requests

Tags: daemon, dogecoin

I have the dogecoin daemon running successfully on Ubuntu, started with this command:

```
dogecoind -daemon
```

It's listening on port 22556, as verified by netstat.

I can also pass commands to it directly via the Ubuntu terminal, like so:

```
dogecoind getinfo
```

However, passing RPC requests to it through HTTP does not work.  The daemon doesn't refuse the connection (and I can verify that it *does* refuse the connection if I use a port other than 22556); instead, the connection hangs, with no data being sent to the client making the HTTP request.  Directly connecting to

```
http://a:b@127.0.0.1:22556/
```

makes the web browser sit and wait for data.  Similarly, making an RPC request via a PHP script, and then accessing that script in a browser, makes the browser wait for 30 second before PHP spits out an error stating that the maximum execution time of 30 seconds was exceeded.

I have my ~/.dogecoin/dogecoin.conf file as such:

```
server=1
rpcuser=a
rpcpassword=b
```

(I know the username and password I typed there are insecure; those are temporary until I can at least make a connection.)

I've tried adding the line

```
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
```

to the end of the config file, but that didn't change the behavior at all.

What am I doing wrong -- why isn't my Dogecoin daemon accepting RPC requests (or any from-an-actual-browser HTTP requests, for that matter)?

**edit**: Also, I can verify that the daemon is caught up with the blockchain.

Comment: rpcallowiip=0.0.0.0 That is an unsafe configuration if you are listening on a public ip address space. The address map 0.0.0.0 is shorthand for allow connections from all hosts. If you are running in a NAT environment you may be ok for the time being as long as you arent' sharing the network with any unknown hosts. (ie a dorm room network) Casey

Comment: @unklStewy: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  I'll be sure to change it before going to production.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  It had to do with adding **rpcallowip** lines to the config file.  Adding these three lines solved it:

```
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=192.168.1.*
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0
```

The last line is what eventually allowed it to work.  I'm not sure why, but netstat said it was listening on 0.0.0.0:22556, so adding 0.0.0.0 to the rpcallowip list solved it.

Comment: That's because 0.0.0.0 in network speak essentially means "all IP's". So you've basically allowed all IP's to connect to your RPC server.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I've since removed it to make sure that vulnerability doesn't exist.

As far as the actual fix, I'm not sure what the issue was.  Running a new installation on a different server, I haven't experienced the same issue that I originally posted about.