# Dogecoin daemon bind error

Tags: dogecoin

I wanted to install a dogecoin client on Debian and compiled myself. After starting it it stoped saying

```
Error: An error occured while setting up the RPC port 22555 for listening:  bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

I am sure that there is no other program using this port and IPv6 also works fine which I tested on my Apache server.

Hopefully you have an idea how to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dogecoin daemon (dogecoind) not responding to RPC requests](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/19141/dogecoin-daemon-dogecoind-not-responding-to-rpc-requests)

Comment: Even though the answers are similar the problems are not. In my case the daemon could not even start because of a bind error. I came across the other thread and tried it and it worked, therefore, I added my solution here.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it somehow, even though I am not sure why this solved it.
I added the following line to the config:

```
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0
```